# AS3 Timer not doing anything in Movieclip Class

Tags: actionscript-3, timer

I have a document class which loops through some JSON data and adds a "tileMc" on the screen with some information in it. I am needing to do something with one of the text fields inside each of the movieclips but the timer is not responding at all, when i trace nothing is coming up.

In the document class i initialize the tile at the start

`public var tileMc: tile;`

Then in a function after ive loaded all the json and everything

```
tileMc = new tile();

                tilePosition += (tileMc.height - 15); //offset between
                tileMc.y = tilePosition;
                tileMc.x = xPos;
                spriteArray.push(tileMc);
                allSprites.push(tileMc);
                var destName = parsedJSON.data[i].destinationCity.toString();
                tileMc.box.departureTime.text = parsedJSON.data[i].scheduledGateTime.toString();
                tileMc.box.destination.text = destName;
                tileMc.box.flightnum.text = (parsedJSON.data[i].airlineCode.toString() + parsedJSON.data[i].flightNumber.toString());
                tileMc.box.status.text = parsedJSON.data[i].remarksWithTime.toString();

                var TF: TextFormat = tileMc.box.status.getTextFormat(0, 1)

                stage.addChild(tileMc);
```

this all works perfectly fine as i want it to.

I have then gone into the Tile class so that i can change the destination.text when its too long

```
package  {

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;

public class tile extends MovieClip {

     public var marqueeTimer:Timer;

    public function tile() {

       trace("TEST 1");
        marqueeTimer = new Timer(0);
        marqueeTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, onMarqueeTick);

    }

    private function onMarqueeTick(ev:TimerEvent): void
    {

        trace("TEST 2");
    }

    public function marquee(delay:int): void
    {
        marqueeTimer.stop();
        if (delay >= 0)
        {
            marqueeTimer.delay = delay;
            marqueeTimer.start();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Only TEST1 is being traced why is the timer not working??

Answer (score 0):

Well maybe use like this :

```
 package  {

        import flash.display.MovieClip;
        import flash.utils.Timer;
        import flash.text.TextField;
        import flash.events.TimerEvent;

        public class tile extends MovieClip {

             public var marqueeTimer:Timer;

            public function tile() {

               trace("TEST 1");
                marqueeTimer = new Timer(0);
                marqueeTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, onMarqueeTick);

                marqueeTimer.start();
            //if u add this. test2 also will be in your output
            }

            private function onMarqueeTick(ev:TimerEvent): void
            {

                trace("TEST 2");
            }

            public function marquee(delay:int): void
            {
                marqueeTimer.stop();
                if (delay >= 0)
                {
                    marqueeTimer.delay = delay;
                    marqueeTimer.start();
                }
            }
        }
        }
```